# Turn off time and Windows update

Tags: windows-7

Okay, yesterday I turned off my computer just like any other day and a Windows update started.. I was okay with that because that stuff rarely appears and when it does it's usually only 1 update, but this time it was 277 updates and the computer was shutting down (and downloading the stuff) the whole night, it took like 5 hours.. Now when I was turning it on it was configuring some stuff and it just restarted and turned on.. Now, is it normal that Windows downloaded 277 updates?
Thanks :D

Comment: What were the updates listed? Sounds like you haven't been running updates for a long time.

Comment: I don't really know how the updates work or how to enable/disable them and stuff like that.. The updates weren't listed at all, it just said something like "Downloaded updates 1 out of 277" or something like that.. Now that doesn't show up, it just turns off normally but now it takes way longer to turn on and I get a short black screen right before the "Welcome" message.

Comment: Yes, it can do hundreds of updates. If you buy a copy of Win 7 now and do a windows update, there will be a lot of updates. I have an 'offline' music PC which is never updated. I got some new hardware and had to do the update... It took about 7 hours

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that that's a normal thing.. I got really worried there.. Nothing can happen to my baby.. Thanks for the info.. :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed windows 8.1 yesterday. I got over 200 update. 
And u can check, did u have some system crash? Some driver oroblem?  Or any other issue, all these messages will be send to Microsoft so they can solve it through update for u. Beside that there is an option in Windows update which u can check, update only windows or all windows softwares on your system. So if u got many updates, it might be all softwares as well.

Comment: I don't know, it might be that because I downloaded Windows Live Essentials yesterday (only Movie Maker though).. Now when I turn off my computer there are no updates but it takes a longer time to turn on, I get a  short black screen right before the "Welcome" message appears..

Comment: And no, I didn't have any system crashes.. I just got this PC a few months ago.. It worked perfectly so far..